# with Flutter, is there a way to only download certain features/modules/parts of an app depending on what a user needs

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-play, app-store

We are very new to mobile development and are evaluating Flutter to build an app for our customers, for android and IOS, that would enhance the use of one of our main product.
Our product interfaces with multiple instruments. It also has many features of its own.

We are trying to build a mobile app where we can keep adding modules to interface different instruments and features on our main product plus have features of its own. But a given user will not be using all of these modules. They may only use interface to a couple of instruments and some main product features.
Is there a way to only download the required modules of the app depending on what the user needs so that my app doesn't get too big and only downloads what it needs to?

For example, the app will be comprised of a shell and 3 features say feature 1, feature 2 and feature 3.
User 1 only wants feature 1 and 3. So the shell app downloads and installs the modules required for feature 1 and 3.
User 2 only wants feature 2. So the shell app downloads and installs the modules required for feature 2 only.

Alternatively, if we build separate apps to all these interfaces instead of modules within a single app, we could end up having to manage a ton of apps. Also, from a users perspective, they will have to keep switching between apps when they could have simply switched between sections within a single app.

Comment: You can use play feature delivery: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery

Comment: thanks a lot..this seems to be what I was looking for. I did some research online and seems this is only supported by android/google play. Is there a counterpart for IOS app store?